# error C1189 after installing Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I installed VS2010 after a drive crash, prior I had VS2005 and everything was fine.

Now on compiling a C++ app that was fine previously I am seeing a couple of errors which I just cannot figure out.

> Error  1   error C1189: #error :  This file requires _WIN32_WINNT to be #defined at least to 0x0403. Value 0x0501 or higher is recommended.    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcore.h   35  1   BIOXGINA

```
#ifndef __ATLCORE_H__
#define __ATLCORE_H__

#pragma once

#ifdef _ATL_ALL_WARNINGS
#pragma warning( push )
#endif

#pragma warning(disable: 4786) // identifier was truncated in the debug information
#pragma warning(disable: 4127) // constant expression

#include <atldef.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ole2.h>

#include <limits.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <mbstring.h>

#include <atlchecked.h>
#include <atlsimpcoll.h>

34.  #if _WIN32_WINNT < 0x0403
35.  #error This file requires _WIN32_WINNT to be #defined at least to 0x0403. Value 0x0501 or higher is recommended.
36.  #endif

#pragma pack(push,_ATL_PACKING)
namespace ATL
{
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Verify that a null-terminated string points to valid memory
inline BOOL AtlIsValidString(
_In_z_count_(nMaxLength) LPCWSTR psz,
_In_ size_t nMaxLength = INT_MAX)
{
(nMaxLength);
return (psz != NULL);
}
```

If I comment out the above lines, I then get

> error C3861 Identifier not found on line 111 below.

I presume I'm only getting this because I commented the above lines ?

```
HRESULT Init() throw()
{
    HRESULT hRes = S_OK;

111.        if (!InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&m_sec, 0))
    {
        hRes = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }

    return hRes;
}
```

I would appreciate any assistance on this. Don't really want to reinstall 2005.

Answer (score 24):

This [Microsoft Connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/564673/problem-with-win32-winnt) has this potential solution:

> edit file "stdafx.h" and change the value defined for _WIN32_WINNT and WINVER to 0x0502.

More discussion here about this [error on the MSDN C++ forum: Problem with older VC Solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/47720e9f-40f7-4c0a-bf59-82b1281464cb).

Comment: Rather than change the system file stdafx.h, I opted to set these in the Preprocessor definitions for my projects. A lot more portable than tinkering with system .h files.

Comment: @PeteMagsig: `stdafx.h` is not a system file.  It's code automatically placed into your project by the New Project wizard, to be a focal point for precompiled headers, but it's not shared with anything else at all.  (The filename is terrible)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't realize that's where stdafx.h came from. I'm still in favor of using preprocessor definitions in the compiler configuration.

Comment: @Pete: I generally use the rule "Will this setting apply to all build configurations, Release, Debug, 32-bit, 64-bit, etc?"  Since I don't build separate binaries for different Windows versions, I don't want it to be a build configuration.  If you tested WINVER and did conditional compilation in your own code, then it would be a configuration setting.

Answer (score 5):

Your project targets a Windows version that is no longer supported by the newer compiler (or anything else).

You have to select a minimum target version that is Windows XP ("Windows 5") or later.

Comment: The compiler doesn't really care, it's libraries that have issues with older Windows versions.  The C runtime library has a couple essential functions that rely on WinXP features for non-essential tasks, making it hard to do away with.  But this particular problem is an ATL dependency on functions introduced in XP.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you both for the replies.

I managed to get rid of the error message as follows. The Context.h looked liked this.

```
  #pragma once

  #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400

  #include <windows.h>
  #include <winwlx.h>
  #include <ObjBase.h>
  #include <comdef.h>
  #include <atlbase.h>

  extern CComModule _Module;

  #include <atlcom.h>
  #include <vector>
```

I moved the  #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400  to then end after all the includes, and it compiled Ok. Odd, but it worked.

I will however alter it to 0x0502 as suggested.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Project Property –> Configuration Properties –> C/C++  -> Command Line   ->Additional Options
：add this code

/D “_WIN32_WINNT=0×0501”

if in Windows server 2003，0×0501chagnes to 0×0502；
if in Windows 7， 0×0501chagnes to   0×0601

works well